# Larravel project has no migration scripts for the database. Does the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase` handles that and how?

Tags: database, laravel, phpunit

I inherited a laravel project to maintain and for various unexplained to me reasons (previous devs are gone, without any way to contact them) has no database migrations for it.

In my code base, I have been tasked to increase the code coverage for the tests. But the tests between them have no isolation whatsoever, therefore in contrary with this [answer][1], some of them may fail due to this reason.

In order to fix this problem I found this [solution][2] provided from laravel itself:

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        // Test something here
    }
}
```

But in my rationale there is the following thorn:

Does this approach work without migration scripts, if no how I can overcome the problem?

And for that, I want your contribution in order to remove it.

[1] https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/394148/249660

[2] https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test

Answer (score 0):

The `RefreshDatabase` trait won't work in this case, because it executes `php artisan migrate:fresh` before each test, but there are no migration scripts to execute.

Did you consider to use the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions` trait? This will wrap each test in a database transaction and will probably give you enough isolation. It doesn't use migrations.

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    ...
```

With this approach your testing database of course has to be setup with all the tables created and you have to alter / migrate the test database manually when you add a new table.

Comment: Well for some reason does not work well does the data factories affect them?

Comment: You have to setup the data with the factories before each test, or you can add the data to the test database.

Comment: Because the functions I am testing have complex postgresql queries I need to use the `create` method when I test the models. Tests in my case has proved that the `DatabaseTransactions` does not remove the test data from the db after the test in my case.